# How can I finish "group" of Activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an operation in my Android app which includes a couple of activities. At the end of this operation, I need to close all of these activities and go back to the screen which starts this operation. Below is a diagram explaining how this should work. Are there are any options to do this?

[image: Diagram]

P/S/ Fragments is not an option in my case

Comment: You can use a chain of `startActivityForResult`s. Or use fragments. Or at least anything that is not an Activity chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Shortly they are:

1. Start all your activity with `startActivityOnResult()` method. And catch if you need to close them

2. start `Activity_1` with cleaning current backstack:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

3. Activities located inside of processes. You can define another process in the `AndroidManifest` for your activities(3,4,5). After that you need to return to previous process and remove current process from backStack.

Comment: The first option sounds interesting, it is realy can help. Second is impossible now because I don't know which activity starts the operation.

Comment: Something similar to the third option I am already tried. I ran my first operation activity with flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, but sometimes (if an application with running activity in the new task was in background) my previous task already was closed at that moment when I closing task of operations. So the application just shuts down when the user pressed OK on the last activity of operation.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `flag=Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` to finish group of activities. 

here is example of code

```
 startActivity(new Intent(SignIn.this, MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
```

Comment: yes, but I don't know to which Activity I need to return because I don't know what Activity is started my operation

Answer (score 1):

you can use `flag=Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` to clear all previous activity . This flag is used to clear all previous activity .

**try this code**

```
 //  go to login activity

Intent intent =newIntent(AddNewCardActivity.this,HomeNavigationActivity.class);
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```