# How to finish last N activites on stack in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, onactivityresult

I have 4 activities:

A->B->C->D

When I go from C to D, I want to finish both B and C so that when I press the back button, activity A is resumed. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56189020/how-can-i-finish-group-of-activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK to set the target activity as new root. This flag should be used in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

```
class ActivityD : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_d)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        Intent(this, ActivityA::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            startActivity(this)
        }
    }
}
```

You can view activity stask using the following adb command (unix shell)

```
adb shell dumpsys activity activities | sed -En -e '/Stack #/p' -e '/Running activities/,/Run #0/p'
```

Comment: This will destroy activity A when starting D, so when I press the back button, in activity D, activity A will be re-created. Is there a way to simply just resume activity A without having to re-create?

Comment: Override onActivityResult method for B and C activity classes and call finish() to destroy them. Of course you should use startActivityForResult to start C and D activities and setResult to close them